# Connection with 3 tables in Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I have 3 tables in a SQL database: `Movies`, `Viewer` and `Movies_Viewer` (= that shows which viewer saw which movie).

The client will insert `Viewer` name and `Movie` name and with the Entity Framework, I want to insert it to the 3 tables I have (with linq for example), but how should I know what ID gets the movie and the viewer to insert it in the third table?

Should I insert to the 2 tables and then call another function that insert the ID's to the third? how do I have all the data?

This is my code - is it wrong to do like this?

```
[WebMethod]
public void InsertToDB(string viewerName, string movieName)
{
    InsertToViewerTbl(viewerName);
    InsertToMoviesTbl(movieName);
}

private void InsertToMoviesTbl(string movieName)
{
    var db = new MoviesEntities1();
    var movieNameTbl = new MovieNameTbl();
    movieNameTbl.MovieName = movieName;

    db.AddToMovieNameTbls(movieNameTbl);
    db.SaveChanges();
}

private void InsertToViewerTbl(string viewerName)
{
    var db = new MoviesEntities1();
    var viewerNameTbl = new ViewerNamesTbl();
    viewerNameTbl.ViewerName = viewerName;

    db.AddToViewerNamesTbls(viewerNameTbl);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just return the objects, after adding them to the db, like :

```
[WebMethod] public void InsertToDB(string viewerName, string movieName) 
{
    var viewer = InsertToViewerTbl(viewerName); 
    var movie = InsertToMoviesTbl(movieName);
    InsertToMovies_Viewer(viewer, movie);
}

private MovieNameTbl InsertToMoviesTbl(string movieName)
{
    var db = new MoviesEntities1();

    var movieNameTbl = new MovieNameTbl();
    movieNameTbl.MovieName = movieName;

    db.AddToMovieNameTbls(movieNameTbl);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return movieNameTbl ;
}

private ViewerNamesTbl InsertToViewerTbl(string viewerName)
{
    var db = new MoviesEntities1();

    var viewerNameTbl = new ViewerNamesTbl();
    viewerNameTbl.ViewerName = viewerName;

    db.AddToViewerNamesTbls(viewerNameTbl);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return viewerNameTbl;
}

private void InsertToMovies_Viewer(ViewerNamesTbl viewer, MovieNameTbl movie)
{
    var db = new MoviesEntities1();

    var movieViewer = new Movies_Viewer();// or however the table is called
    movieViewer.Viewer = viewer; // or however the column is called
    movieViewer.Movie= movie; // or however the column is called

    db.AddToMovies_Viewer(movieViewer);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

But I'd advise you to do this in one method, so you won't create the connection every time, and save the changes every time :

```
[WebMethod] public void InsertToDB(string viewerName, string movieName) 
{
    var db = new MoviesEntities1();

    var movie = new MovieNameTbl();
    movieNameTbl.MovieName = movieName;

    db.AddToMovieNameTbls(movieNameTbl);

    var viewer = new ViewerNamesTbl();
    viewerNameTbl.ViewerName = viewerName;

    db.AddToViewerNamesTbls(viewerNameTbl);

    var movieViewer = new Movies_Viewer();// or however the table is called
    movieViewer.Viewer = viewer; // or however the column is called
    movieViewer.Movie= movie; // or however the column is called

    db.AddToMovies_Viewer(movieViewer);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to do this **in one step** using the Entity Framework's built-in "navigation properties". Assuming that your `Movie` class has a `Viewers` navigation property, you should do:

```
private void InsertToMovies(string movieName, string viewerName)
{
    using (var db = new MoviesEntities1())
    {
         // create the new movie, set its name
         var newMovie = new MovieNameTbl();
         newMovie.MovieName = movieName;

         // create the new viewer, set its name
         var viewer = new ViewerNamesTbl();
         viewer.ViewerName = viewerName;

         // add the viewer to the new movie instance
         newMovie.Viewers.Add(viewer);

         // add movie to the database context and save it   
         db.AddToMovieNameTbls(movieNameTbl);
         db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

With this, Entity Framework will do all the heavy lifting - you don't need to know any `ID`, you don't need to do any second insert, you don't need to handle the "link" table - all that is handled by Entity Framework for you.